# How to get StringBuilder From user

Tags: java

how can i get `StringBuilder` from users through `Scanner` class??
or any other classes?
i know that we can get a string and then put it in a `StringBuilder` like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sade {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str;

        str = scan.nextLine();
        StringBuilder strb  = new StringBuilder(str);
    }
}
```

or through using `append()`.
but is there anyway to get `StringBuilder` directly from user??

Comment: No, user can only pass you a String. It can't pass a StringBuilder.

Comment: Why you want a StringBuilder? If you use `+` on Strings, it will be turned into a StringBuilder at compile-time.

Comment: Ask the user to buy a StringBuilder object from eBay and give it to you in System.in :))  System.in is an input stream and String Builder is an object to hold and concatenate Strings. You will not succeed your task if you start fishing 3 classes and searching the "auto-generetare source code" key on your keyboard. Take a look at code snippets : 5-15 row, and quick java course: 1-2 week. Otherwise you need to ask each second line of the code how to combine

Comment: because StringBuilder is more dynamic.it has some methods like insert that makes it more dynamic than string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot fetch a `StringBuilder` object from the Standard Input, but you can output to the user `enter the strings (type 'exit' to exit):` and formulate your own.

Loop through this until they type 'exit', and each time you fetch the string, you can do `myStringBuilder.add(theirInput)`
(this, of course, is pseudo-code)

Answer (score 6):

You misunderstand the **StringBuilder** Class.The principal operations of a StringBuilder are the append and insert methods, which are overloaded so as to accept data of any type. Each effectively converts a given datum to a string and then appends or inserts the characters of that string to the string builder. The append method always adds these characters at the end of the builder; the insert method adds the characters at a specified point.
The best thing you can do with your code is :-

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class sb {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            StringBuilder strb  = new StringBuilder(scan.nextLine());
            strb.append( scan.nextLine());
            System.out.println(strb);
        }
    }
```

Ofcourse,it is the same as you posted!

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstand the purpose of `StringBuilder`. String concatenation requires creating a new `String` which causes unnecessary garbage collection. `StringBuilder` appends multiple strings together by putting their contents in a character buffer and then returning a new string all at once. This causes a lot of garbage collection:

```
while ( (line = scanner.nextLine()) != null)
    dataSoFar += line;
```

Each iteration through that causes the old String object referenced by `dataSoFar` to be concatenated into a new `String` with `line`. `StringBuilder` merely reads `line` and puts its characters onto the end of the internal buffer. When it needs to, it'll resize the buffer which requires a lot less GC work when reading a big source of character data.

Java's API doesn't return you a string builder because it would make no sense here.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to read all lines type in by the user into a StringBuilder this can be accomplished with something like this:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String text=null;
while ((text = scan.nextLine ()) != null)
{
      sb.append(text);
}
```